# CSS stylesheet not linking to html

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to use a stylesheet for the background-image of my html page. And it just isn't linking or just isn't working. (Yes html and css files are all within the same directory/folder).

This is my code that I have used

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
<center> <p style="border:1px solid white; padding:15px; color:blue;      font-family:courier; font-size:200%;"> Welcome
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

and then the stylesheet code itself contains this. and even in the link type, i have tried using /png/image.

```
body {
        background-image: url("image-name-here.png");
        backgound-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
}
```

and yes i have tried replacing the tag body with head.

Comment: where is body tag in your html?

Comment: you are missing body tag in your HTML

Comment: It won't because you didn't have body and the size of the body by default is zero height and zero width. So you should declare background-size: cover or something.

Comment: I do have the body tag, but the link for the css isn't inside the body tag

Comment: Your markup is invalid.

Comment: Guys, he does have a body tag. Hush. It should however, be outside of the head tag.

Answer (score 1):

You had a spelling mistake in `background-repeat`, you spelled it as `backgound-repeat`. Also, if you haven't already, there needs to be a `<body></body>` tag in the HTML.

Update the **HTML**,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**,

Fix the mistake in your stylesheet,

```
body {
   background-image: url("image-name-here.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center top;
}
```